# Can I use char[] or char* as a function's return value?

Tags: c, arrays, char, return-type, function-calls

I want to know (I tried to but program freezes) if there's a way to create a function that returns a char* or a char[], so I don't have to modify the String I'm sending to the function, to learn how to make my code more eloquent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LOW_LETTERS 97
#define CAP_LETTERS 65
#define N_LETTERS 26
#define DIFF 32
#define NUMBERS 48
#define N_DIGITS 9


void transformText ( char text[] )
{
    for ( int i = 0 ; text[i] != '\0' ; i++ )
    {
        if ( ( text[i] >= LOW_LETTERS ) && ( text[i]  <= LOW_LETTERS + N_LETTERS ) )
            text[ i ] = text [ i ] - DIFF ; //same letter, but upper case
        else
            if ( ( text [ i ] >= CAP_LETTERS ) && ( text[i] <= CAP_LETTERS + N_LETTERS ) )
                text [ i ] = text [ i ] + DIFF ; //same letter, but lower case
            else
                if ( text [i] >= NUMBERS && text[i] <= NUMBERS + N_DIGITS )
                    text[i] = '*'; //turns every number to a '*'
    }

}

int main (void)
{
    char text[] = "foOo123Oo44O99oO00" ;
    transformText ( text ) ;
    printf ( "%s\n", text ) ; //prints FOoO***oO**o**Oo**

    return 0 ;
}
```

This is the way I solved it, I think I'm having a memory leak thought, ain't I? Notice that I'm not modifying the original String, which is what I was intending to do, also I don't really know where to put the `free(newText)` so it is recognized, but still usable for `main()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LOW_LETTERS 97
#define CAP_LETTERS 65
#define N_LETTERS 26
#define DIFF 32
#define NUMBERS 48
#define N_DIGITS 9
#define BUFFER 128


char* transformText ( char text[] )
{
    char *newText = (char *) malloc (BUFFER) ;
    for ( int i = 0 ; text[i] != '\0' ; i++ )
    {
        if ( ( text[i] >= LOW_LETTERS ) && ( text[i]  <= LOW_LETTERS + N_LETTERS ) )
            newText[ i ] = text [ i ] - DIFF ; //same letter, but upper case
        else
            if ( ( text [ i ] >= CAP_LETTERS ) && ( text[i] <= CAP_LETTERS + N_LETTERS ) )
                newText [ i ] = text [ i ] + DIFF ; //same letter, but lower case
            else
                if ( text [i] >= NUMBERS && text[i] <= NUMBERS + N_DIGITS )
                    newText[i] = '*'; //turns every number to a '*'
                else
                    newText[i] = text[i] ;
    }

    return newText ;
}

int main (void)
{
    char text[] = "foOo123Oo44O99oO00" ;

    printf ( "%s\n", transformText ( text ) ) ; //prints FOoO***oO**o**Oo**
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: You can return `char *` but you also have to think about whereabouts in memory the modified string will live.

Comment: yes it's a simple pointer thing.. you can have pointers as returned values of functions

Comment: @M.M I did it this way, because I couldn't make it the way I'm asking, in my original idea, I wouldn't modify the string.

Comment: Functions can't return arrays, so `char []` is not allowed.  But `char *` is very common.

Comment: you can return `char*` from a function, if you get any error just cast the variable into `char*` when you return it. example - `return (char*) text;`

Comment: thanks @JonathanLeffler good to know.

Comment: Memory leak is when you dynamically allocate memory (malloc family of functions) and never free that memory. When you work with arrays, you are safe from memory leaking, you don't free that.

Comment: that's exactly what I did, check the edit @SelçukCihan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, yes, you are all good to have a function that returns a `char *`, but you need to be careful about a few things, like

- You need to be sure not to return the address of a local variable to the called function. That will create the issue of using an invalid memory in the caller. The preferable way is to allocate memory using `malloc()` or family and return the pointer. You need to `free()` the memory also, once you're done using it.
- If you're going to make use of the returned pointer, you need to make sure of the validity of the returned pointer.

---

EDIT:

So, once you got the returned pointer in the caller and done with it's usage, you need to release the memory allocated earlier by calling `free()` and passing the pointer. In your case, it should look like

```
char * res = transformText ( text );
printf ( "%s\n", res );   // use the returned pointer
free(res);                                  // release memory
return 0 ;                                   // done
```

Comment: Thanks, man! I did it like this and it works... still I think I'm missing something about the `free()`, I mean if I free that memory in the function transformText, then I wouldn't be able to show it in `main()`, right? but main doesn't know who is char *newText, because I defined it on that other function.

Comment: please, check the edit... can't reply you with the new code.

Comment: but then that function wouldn't really return anything... it would just modify the text variable, I was thinking of sending text through an array, and receive a pointer from a function, but I guess is like I told RoadRunner about his answer. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @newbie Oops, i overlooked, now it's fine. :)

Comment: Yes, I thought that was the only way too, but that way I'm losing the whole point of what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Since functions can't return arrays, you need to return a pointer from the heap. The reason you can't return arrays is because they get declared on the stack, and get erased when the function returns. Whereas if you return a pointer instead, you can share this pointer throughout your program.

Your code would be roughly like this:

```
char* transformText(const char text[]) {
    char *result = malloc(........);
    /* check malloc */
    /* more code */
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    const char text[] = "foOo123Oo44O99oO00";
    char *result = transformText(text);
    /* do more stuff */

    /* deallocate pointer */
    free(result);
}
```

Here is another example which shows that you can still use `void()` for your function, and not return anything:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void allocate(const char text[], char **result) {
    *result = malloc(strlen(text)+1);
}

int main(void) {
    const char text[] = "foOo123Oo44O99oO00";
    char *result; 

    allocate(text, &result);
    strcpy(result, text);

    printf("%s\n", result);

    free(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I also thought that's the way it had to be done, but I was just trying to make something more expressive, you know? like `printf ("%s\n", transformText(text))`  but I guess I can't do it that way, and free the allocated memory with no reference to it. I suppose, I'm just gonna have to declare a static reference to a pointer to be able to hold that address, but is the same thing than using a `void transormText (char *text)` and then free the char * on the main function, I mean transformText, would just modify that pointer and not return it, cause I wouldn't need that.

Comment: @newbie You can use `void()` to do this, but the approach above is the easiest way to do it. I edited the answer to include another example.

Comment: I know I can, I was just wondering if there was a way to not use a `void()` function but a `char*` function.

Comment: @newbie Glad I could help :).

Answer (score 0):

Most often, you don't want to return a `char*` from a function. There is no obvious benefit of doing so in your case.

Alternatives are either to have the caller make a copy:

```
const char text[] = "foOo123Oo44O99oO00";
char text_copy [strlen(text)+1];
memcpy(text_copy, text, sizeof(text));
transformText (text_copy);
```

or to have the function do it:

```
void transformText (char* dst, const char* src)
{
  // iterate over src
  // store result in dst
}
```

There is no obvious reason why dynamic allocation would be beneficial here. To use dynamic memory rather sounds like a side-effect caused by a bad program design. Returning pointers to dynamic memory should be avoided, since it gives a high potential for memory leaks.

Whenever possible, leave allocation to the caller.

Answer (score -3):

it is very straight:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LOW_LETTERS 97
#define CAP_LETTERS 65
#define N_LETTERS 26
#define DIFF 32
#define NUMBERS 48
#define N_DIGITS 9


char* transformText ( char text[] )
{
for ( int i = 0 ; text[i] != '\0' ; i++ )
{
if ( ( text[i] >= LOW_LETTERS ) && ( text[i]  <= LOW_LETTERS + N_LETTERS ) )
text[ i ] = text [ i ] - DIFF ; //same letter, but upper case
else
if ( ( text [ i ] >= CAP_LETTERS ) && ( text[i] <= CAP_LETTERS + N_LETTERS ) )
text [ i ] = text [ i ] + DIFF ; //same letter, but lower case
else
if ( text [i] >= NUMBERS && text[i] <= NUMBERS + N_DIGITS )
text[i] = '*'; //turns every number to a '*'
}
return text;

}

int main (void)
{
char text[] = "foOo123Oo44O99oO00" ;
char* text2 = transformText ( text ) ;
printf ( "%s\n", text ) ; //prints FOoO***oO**o**Oo**
printf ( "%s\n", text2 ) ; //prints FOoO***oO**o**Oo**
free(text2);
return 0 ;
}
```

returns same value: 
[image]